# Automatically assigning shorter column names to large dataset and retaining original names as labels

Tags: r, excel, label, survey

I have a large dataset with around 200 columns. The original file is in Excel, with the first row including variable names. The variable names are all survey questions and so they're a bit unwieldy to work with (e.g. "What is your current weight?")

I have used:

```
df = read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet = 1)
```

This is fine, but I end up with very long column names which are hard to work with.

As there are many columns, is there any way of automatically assigning a short and manageable name to each column, while retaining the original full names as labels?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create and use a simple lookup vector and rename the long names to "Q1", "Q2" etc. and when needed change the names back.

Below is one approach using dplyr (for other approaches I've written a [blog post](https://tim-tiefenbach.de/post/2022-rename-columns/) covering base R, data.table and python).

```r
library(dplyr)

# create a lookup vector
lookup_vec <- setNames(names(iris),
                       paste0("Q", seq_along(iris)))

# rename columns to have short names when working with the data
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  rename(any_of(lookup_vec))

iris2 %>% glimpse()
#> Rows: 150
#> Columns: 5
#> $ Q1 <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.~
#> $ Q2 <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.~
#> $ Q3 <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.~
#> $ Q4 <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.~
#> $ Q5 <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, set~

# change names back for output reports
lookup_vec2 <- setNames(names(lookup_vec), lookup_vec)

iris %>% 
  rename(any_of(lookup_vec2)) %>% 
  glimpse() # for better printing
#> Rows: 150
#> Columns: 5
#> $ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.~
#> $ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.~
#> $ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.~
#> $ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.~
#> $ Species      <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, s~
```

To generate more "meaningful" short names we can use `base::abbreviate()` to create the lookup vector:

```r
lookup_vec <- setNames(names(iris),
                       abbreviate(names(iris)))
lookup_vec
#>           Sp.L           Sp.W           Pt.L           Pt.W           Spcs 
#> "Sepal.Length"  "Sepal.Width" "Petal.Length"  "Petal.Width"      "Species"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much for this! This worked well. Is there any way to also set the original column names as column labels?